# Create binary columns after groupby based on occurrence

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

An empty df w particular cols of interest (col1-5)

```
dfw_columns = pd.DataFrame({
    "col1": [],
    "col2": [],
    "col3": [],
    "col4": [],
    "col5": []
})
```

The df w actual entries

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi", "ghi"],
    "colids": ["col1", "col33", np.nan, "col5", "col1", "col2", np.nan]

})
```

Place values in the dfw_columns based on occurrence (1 or 0) in df for each Name and colids.

Desired output (after filling the empty dfw_columns)

```
desireddf = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["abc", "def", "ghi"],
    "col1": [1,1, 0],
    "col2": [0,0, 1],
    "col3": [0,0, 0],
    "col4": [0,0, 0],
    "col5": [0,1,0]
})
desireddf
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you can `pd.crosstab` + `.reindex`:

```py
cols_of_interest = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5']

out = pd.crosstab(df['Name'], df['colids']).reindex(columns=cols_of_interest, fill_value=0)
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
colids  col1  col2  col3  col4  col5
Name                                
abc        1     0     0     0     0
def        1     0     0     0     1
ghi        0     1     0     0     0
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `pivot` as follows.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "Name": ["abc", "abc", "abc", "def", "def", "ghi", "ghi"],
    "colids": ["col1", "col3", np.nan, "col5", "col1", "col2", np.nan]

})

df = df.dropna()

df['value'] = 1

df.pivot(index = 'Name', columns = 'colids', values = 'value').fillna(0)
```

The result is as follows (Note that your df does not include col4).

```
colids  col1    col2    col3    col5
Name                
abc     1.0     0.0     1.0      0.0
def     1.0     0.0     0.0      1.0
ghi     0.0     1.0     0.0      0.0
```

Comment: It does not include col4 but it has to be returned w all 0's in it.